# Does the API allow us to pull down a user's subscriptions?

Tags: support

When I joined the site, I found that I could subscribe to hear about new posts within my favorite tag/filter. I started receiving daily emails with the latest posts in those categories. I can't find that list of subscriptions in my profile or in the API. Am I just missing it?

Answer (score 1):

This data isn't exposed in the API.

Tagset subscriptions are exposed as RSS feeds by stackexchange.com however.

[image]

Comment: couldn't this data be added then? It must readily available if it's in the RSS feeds?